# How to run Luis Recogniser on ChoicePrompt

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework

I have a `ChoicePrompt` with two options.

```
[    {
        value: 'credit',
        synonyms: ['titanium', 'world', 'credit', 'mastercard'],
    },
    {
        value: 'visaPrepaid',
        synonyms: ['platinium', 'visa', 'prepaid', 'prepaid card', 'visa prepaid']
    },]
```

The user can either click on the suggested action or type directly on the textbot "I want a credit card"

I wish to run on a Luis query recognition on this text and extract whether the user wanted a credit or a prepaid card. However, I don't know how to interect that string.

I use a `WaterfallDialog` to show the prompt

Comment: You want to get the choicePrompt value ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways to build a ChoicePrompt. I use `ChoiceFactory.forChannel()` to do so. I'm then using `imBack` which returns the choice as a user text input. Alternatively, you could do a `postBack`, which would act as more of a trigger, and capture the sent value.

In my case, since the choice is returned as a user text input, I grab the text value from the activity and send that to LUIS. I'm matching on the `Greeting` intent which, if successful, then returns the intent found.

Hope of help!

```js
async choiceStep ( stepContext ) {
  const stepResult = stepContext.context.activity.text;

  if ( stepResult ) {
    const message = ChoiceFactory.forChannel(
      stepContext.context, [
        { value: 'Hello', action: { type: 'imBack', title: 'Hello', value: 'Hello' } },
        { value: 'What is the date?', action: { type: 'imBack', title: 'What is the date?', value: 'What is the date?' } }
      ], `Which do you choose?`
    );
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity( message );
  }
  return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
}

  async choiceLuisStep ( stepContext ) {
  if ( stepContext.context.activity.text ) {
    const stepResults = stepContext.context.activity.text;
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity( `You said: ${ stepResults }` );

    const recognizerResult = await this.recognizer.recognize( stepContext.context );
    let intent = await LuisRecognizer.topIntent( recognizerResult );

    if ( intent === 'Greeting' ) {
      await stepContext.context.sendActivity( `Luis recognized: ${ intent }` );
      return stepContext.next();
    } else {
      await stepContext.context.sendActivity( 'No LUIS intent was found.' );
      return stepContext.next();
    }
  } else {
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity( 'Thanks for visiting!' );
    return stepContext.next();
  }
}
```

[image]